# Выборка из базы. Исключить некоторые записи

Tags: mysql

Делаю выборку из базы

```
$vib = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vibor` WHERE `category` = '2' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

Выводит все статьи у которых `category = 2`.
Под такие статьи попадает статья с `id = 15`.
Как исключить ее из этого списка, не меняя для нее значение `category = 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `vibor` WHERE `category` = '2' AND `id` <> '15' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

[Описание операторов сравнения](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо. только там где id нужны такие ковычки ` ` иначе не работает)

Comment: @Денис, спасибо, исправил.